# Referencing XSD from XML

Tags: xml, namespaces, xsd

I've been looking for a way to attach an XSD to an XML file so that a program openning that XML can access to the corresponding XSD, but all the anwers i found included the use of a namespace without even a single explaination about it.

I only have an XSD, i don't have a "namespace" or whatever that is. How can i just reference my XSD into an XML file ?

Comment: You are probably referring to [Using Inline Schemas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759142%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and its use of namespaces. Basically you can adopt the example there without the use of this namespace `xmlns:x="urn:book"` - it is only truly needed if you have to distinguish between `book` elements defined in multiple schemas you could be referencing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i want to keep the two files separate, i just need to reference the XSD from the XML

Answer (score 1):

If you have a schema without a `targetNamespace` then you can attach it to a non-namespaced XML file using `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` on the root element

```
<example xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schema.xsd">
```

A validating parser will attempt to resolve the schema location as a relative URL against the location of the XML document, you may want to use an absolute URL rather than a relative one if the schema and document are not in the same place.

```
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://example.com/schema.xsd"
```

Comment: Thanks, but what does this line do : xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ?

Comment: @Virus721 it declares the `xsi` namespace prefix which is then used for the schema location attribute.  The namespace only applies to names that use the `xsi:` prefix, it doesn't put the rest of the elements in your document into a namespace.

Comment: Do I have to use this URL ? Why do I even have to use an URL ? Does it retrieve something from the given URL ? How do you choose the URL ?

Comment: @Virus721 namespace URIs simply identify a particular namespace, they aren't URLs that anything will be retrieved from.  The `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance` namespace is part of the schema specification - the way you link a (non-namespaced) document to its schema is using an attribute with the namespace `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance` and the local name `noNamespaceSchemaLocation`.

Comment: @Virus721 W3C specifications tend to name their namespaces with URIs that look like `http:` URLs, but other specifications use more opaque URN identifiers like `urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog`.

Comment: Using an URL to identify something and not referencing an actual URL seems completly counter intuitive and confusing to me, but ok.
Now what if i want to use a namespace ? (i guess it's better). I saw the following code : `xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com note.xsd">` Why is it referencing http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance if it has a namespace ?

Comment: @Virus721 again, that's the schema specification saying that the attribute you use to link a namespace to its corresponding schema must go in the `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance` namespace (and the conventional way to achieve that is to map it to the `xsi` prefix). The elements in your document are in the `http://www.w3schools.com` namespace, the `schemaLocation` attribute is in the XMLSchema-instance namespace

Comment: @Virus721 in this instance the schema would also need to declare `http://www.w3schools.com` as its `targetNamespace`